# Python tkinter : browse directory and save to new directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to open a new browser by clicking Button from python tkinker GUI and new directory need to be saved and display on GUI.

I am able to open current directory with command below;

```
import os
subprocess.Popen('explorer "C:\temp"')
cur_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

my question is how to save the active browser dir and display on GUI after Step A/B above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the imports needed for this answer:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk # if using Python 3
import Tkinter as tk # if using Python 2
```

Let's say that your button has been defined.

Here is some sample code which will get the current directory:

```
curr_directory = os.getcwd() # will get current working directory
```

If you're looking to set up a GUI to ask the user to select a file, use:

```
name = tkinter.tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = curr_directory,title = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
print(name)
```

Which will store the file that they have chosen, with the directory they start at set to `curr_directory` which is the current directory.

If you are instead looking to set up a GUI in which the user chooses a directory, you can use:

```
dir_name = tk.tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
```

This will store the name of the directory they have chosen in the `dir_name` variable.

For more information, check out [this link](https://pythonspot.com/en/tk-file-dialogs/) on how to use the file dialog. Alternatively, you can check the general `tkinter` documentation [here (for Python 2)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) and [here (for Python 3)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html). If you need a reference to the file dialog, [this](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/tkFileDialog.html) is a good source.